# Gmail add SENT or DRAFT label

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I have an mbox file that I got using Gmail's "archive" functionality.  Each message in it has an "X-Gmail-Labels" header listing which labels/folders it goes in.  When I import the messages from the mbox file into a new Gmail account (by opening the file in Thunderbird and copying the messages over), the message copies in the new Gmail account still have the X-Gmail-Labels header, but it doesn't do anything - messages are not actually marked with any labels.  So I wrote a script to use the Gmail API to fetch each message, read its X-Gmail-Labels, and add those labels to the message.  This mostly works, except that for two of the labels (SENT and DRAFT), I get an error that says it's an invalid label.  Those label IDs definitely do exist.  How do I add them to messages?

Here's the request I'm making:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH_TOKEN" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST \
-d '{"addLabelIds": ["SENT"]}' \
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/MESSAGE_ID/modify
```

Here's the response body:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Invalid label: SENT"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid label: SENT"
 }
}
```

(Note: my actual script is in Python, but it's easier to see what's going on in curl.)

Comment: Thollie's answer below is correct, see: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels for description of which labels can be applied to messages after they exist in the mailbox, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SENT`- and `DRAFT`-labels are special in that they can not be added to a message once it has been created. More information about each label can be found in [this guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels).

Instead, you could [insert your messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert) and give them the right labels right away.

Here is an example, just encoding an example message in the Developer Console:

**A sent message**

```
var encodedMessage = btoa([
  'From: example@gmail.com', '\r\n',
  'To: example@gmail.com', '\r\n',
  'Subject: cool subject', '\r\n', 
  '\r\n',
  'this is my sent message'
].join(''))
```

**Request**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
 "raw": "RnJvbTogZW10aG9saW5AZ21haWwuY29tDQpUbzogZW10aG9saW5AZ21haWwuY29tDQpTdWJqZWN0OiBjb29sIHN1YmplY3QNCg0KdGhpcyBpcyBteSBzZW50IG1lc3NhZ2U=",
 "labelIds": [
  "SENT"
 ]
}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "id": "1525643b0785e7d7",
 "threadId": "1525643b0785e7d7",
 "labelIds": [
  "SENT"
 ]
}
```

**A draft**

**Request**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
 "raw": "RnJvbTogZW10aG9saW5AZ21haWwuY29tDQpUbzogZW10aG9saW5AZ21haWwuY29tDQpTdWJqZWN0OiBjb29sIHN1YmplY3QNCg0KdGhpcyBpcyBteSBzZW50IG1lc3NhZ2U=",
 "labelIds": [
  "DRAFT"
 ]
}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "id": "1525644c9553906d",
 "threadId": "1525644c9553906d",
 "labelIds": [
  "DRAFT"
 ]
}
```

Also, if you want the created time to be the same as the `Date`-header in the inserted message, make sure you pass along the query parameter `internalDateSource` with the value of `dateHeader`.

Comment: @EricDeFriez Cool. That's a really handy sheet!

Comment: I have confirmed that this works, thanks!  One note though: when inserting messages via the API, it adds a new Received header with the current time, so you need to specify internalDateSource=dateHeader, otherwise the message's display time (when viewing a list of messages in the Gmail web interface) is whenever you inserted it.

Comment: @Avril That's correct :) Will add it to the answer. Thanks!